# Enviar mensagem de confirmação JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Possuo um método para enviar Email via PHP que está funcionando corretamente.

Gostaria apenas que ao final, enviasse uma resposta para o usuário, por um `alert` do javascript mesmo.

Meu formulário está assim:

```
<form  class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nome *</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email *</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Telefone</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefone">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Empresa</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="empresa">
        </div>                        
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Assunto *</label>
            <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Mensagem *</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
        </div>                        
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" required="required">Enviar Mensagem</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

E este é o meu método para enviar o Email.

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $status = array(
        'type'=>'success',
        'message'=>'Email enviado!'
    );

    //pega os atributos do form
    $name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
    $email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
    $telefone = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['telefone'])); 
    $empresa = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['empresa'])); 
    $subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
    $message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 


    $email_from = $email;
    $email_to = 'email@email.com';//email remetente

    //elabora o texto 
    $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Telefone: ' . $telefone . "\n\n" . 'Empresa: ' .  $empresa . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' .  $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

    //envia o email
    $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

    //verifica se foi enviado e redireciona para a página
    if(success){
        //tentei adicionar esse alert, porem sem sucesso
        echo "<script>alert(\"Mensagem enviada com sucesso!\")</script>";
       //redireciona para o index
        header("Location: index.html");
   }
    die;
```

Como dito no comentário do script, tentei adicionar a mensagem antes de redirecionar para minha index, porém sem sucesso.

Comment: Ao enviar o formulário, você já está realizando um redirect (para `sendemail.php`). Uma alternativa seria redirecionar para uma página que exibe uma mensagem de sucesso. Outra alternativa, mais robusta, é utilizar ajax para enviar o email. Pesquise sobre ajax na internet, conteúdo não falta...

Comment: @Oeslei, Vou estudar essa forma com ajax, obrigado pela sugestão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está misturando coisas. PHP é executado no servidor enquanto que JS é executado no cliente (navegador). Escrever JS via PHP é possível mas não é uma boa prática.

Para resolver este problema, remova o `header` do PHP e inclua `window.location.href`, ficando assim:

```
echo '
    <script>
        alert("Mensagem enviada com sucesso!");
        window.location.href = "index.html";
    </script>
';
```

Ainda assim, como o @Oeslei comentou, sugiro redirecionar para outra página que exibe a mensagem ou fazer o envio por AJAX.

Comment: Desta forma, ele não me redireciona para i **index.html**, ele apenas mostra que que esta dentro da ('') na página **sendemail.php**.

Comment: Vou estudar essa forma com ajax, obrigado pela sugestão.

Comment: Experimente remover o `die` ou o `header('Content-type: application/json');`, pq aqui está funcionando

Comment: Realmente, era o header que estava bloqueando. Obrigado pela ajuda